# zend add checkbox to multi checkbox

Tags: zend-framework

I'm looking to do the equivalent of

```
    $element->addMultiOption('value', 'text');
```

which works for multi select dropdowns.

I can't seem to figure the equivalent is fro multi checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
$multichekboxElement = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox("name_for_your_multicheckbox");
$multicheckboxElement->addMultiOption(1,'text-1');
$multicheckboxElement->addMultiOption(2,'text-2');
$multicheckboxElement->addMultiOption(3,'text-3');
$multicheckboxElement->addMultiOption(4,'text-4');
```

Then you just have to add the *"multicheckboxElement" variable to your Form as normal.

Comment: how do you add a title to the checkbox element?

Answer (score 1):

Their is no difference between

```
 $element->addMultiOption('value', 'text');
```

For multiCheckbox elements and multiselect elements.
Error was cause elsewhere